# What is "Exit 2" from finished background job status?

Tags: bash, command-line, background-process, job-control, exit

I have an exercise to put in a file some data (*conf from some directories) and need to do this in background. I did it and I am wondering what is the meaning of output messages:

```
[A@localhost tests]$ ls -ld /etc/*conf /usr/*conf > test1_6_conf.txt 2>&1 &
```

Enter rises this row:

```
[1] 2533
```

what does it mean?
After other Enter, another messages appear

```
[A@localhost tests]$
[1]+  Exit 2                  ls --color=auto -ld /etc/*conf /usr/*conf > test1_6_conf.txt 2>&1
```

What does it mean? What is "Exit 2"?

Enter an check results - seems to be all OK.

```
[A@localhost tests]$
[A@localhost tests]$ ls -l test1_6_conf.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 A A 2641 Nov 22 14:19 test1_6_conf.txt
[A@localhost tests]$
```

I am using CentOS 6.4, Gnome Terminal Emulator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What does it mean? What is "Exit 2"?

It is exit status of `ls`. See man for ls:

```
   Exit status:
       0      if OK,

       1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),

       2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

I guess the reason is that you have lots of *conf files in `/etc` and no *conf files in /usr. In fact `ls -ld /usr/*conf;` would have had the same effect.

So If I do on my computer `ls` for an existing file:

```
ls main.cpp; echo $?
main.cpp
0
```

And for a file that does not exists:

```
ls main.cppp; echo $?
ls: cannot access main.cppp: No such file or directory
2
```

Or as a background process ls for a a file that does not exists:

```
>ls main.cppp &
[1] 26880
ls: cannot access main.cppp: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 2                  ls main.cppp
```

Comment: O! Thanks. Now I've realized that `ls /usr/*conf` return `2` since there no any filenames containing "conf".

Comment: @ALZ, note that it returns 2 because it cannot find the file called `/usr/*conf`. And *`bash`* is passing it that filename because it can't find files that match that pattern. Better shells like `zsh` would have returned a "no match" error and not run `ls` at all.