# ls error code 2

Tags: ls, exit-status

I was reading the man of ls and in the end it talks about the Exit status of ls. It says:

```
   Exit status:
   0      if OK,
   1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),
   2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

But the thing is that i don't understand what they mean by:

> cannot access command-line argument

I have never encountered a situation where i could not acces the arguments passed to my program and i was searching on the web about this particular situation and i couldn't get many information other then [this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102201/what-is-exit-2-from-finished-background-job-status)
which wasn't really clear to me and i was unable to reproduce the error. I'm not sure if i'm miss understanding the MAN page

Comment: Note that this is specific to GNU `ls`. A standard-compliant `ls` just needs to exit with a positive non-zero exit status when encountering an error.

Comment: @Kusalananda An `ls` implementation that choose to emit 50 different error codes, all above 0, is still a POSIX standard compliant implementation. But yes that the GNU implementation of `ls` has decided to assign an error number of two to some error cases is specific to GNU ls.

Comment: @Isaac I don't think I meant anything else by that old comment.

Answer (score 6):

For GNU `ls`, use the source Luke: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=bf0c5941d7de699fc5a85d44461ef29192216d9d;hb=HEAD

You will find many cases where the return code is 2, and some are easy to trigger, as shown below.

First you can read in it:

```
 802 /* Exit statuses.  */
 803 enum
 804   {
 805     /* "ls" had a minor problem.  E.g., while processing a directory,
 806        ls obtained the name of an entry via readdir, yet was later
 807        unable to stat that name.  This happens when listing a directory
 808        in which entries are actively being removed or renamed.  */
 809     LS_MINOR_PROBLEM = 1,
 810 
 811     /* "ls" had more serious trouble (e.g., memory exhausted, invalid
 812        option or failure to stat a command line argument.  */
 813     LS_FAILURE = 2
 814   };
```

So you can see already that value 2 covers more cases than what is written in the documentation.

Then if you search further for `LS_FAILURE` in the code you find out about different cases:

## Case 1

```
1896         case 'w':
1897           if (! set_line_length (optarg))
1898             die (LS_FAILURE, 0, "%s: %s", _("invalid line width"),
1899                  quote (optarg));
1900           break;
```

`set_line_length` will react depending on how `xstrtoumax` returns for the given width. If you look closer at the source code of it you can arrive at some edge cases:

```
$ ls -w -1 >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
2
$ ls -w 1 >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

## Case 2

```
1964         case 'T':
1965           tabsize = xnumtoumax (optarg, 0, 0, SIZE_MAX, "",
1966                                 _("invalid tab size"), LS_FAILURE);
1967           break;
```

Similar to previous case:

```
$ ls -T 1 >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ ls -T -1 >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
2
```

## Case 3

```
2106         default:
2107           usage (LS_FAILURE);
```

So that is the default error code if you provide invalid parameters.
See this example:

```
$ ls --unknown-option >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
2
```

## Case 4

```
2198               if (strchr (p1 + 1, '\n'))
2199                 die (LS_FAILURE, 0, _("invalid time style format %s"),
2200                      quote (p0));
```

This happens when you are providing invalid time format, with two `\n`:

```
$ ls -l --time-style=+%T >& /dev/null ; echo $?
0
$ ls -l --time-style=+%T$'\n' >& /dev/null ; echo $?
0
$ ls -l --time-style=+%T$'\n'%T >& /dev/null ; echo $?
0
$ ls -l --time-style=+%T$'\n'%T$'\n' >& /dev/null ; echo $?
2
```

## Case 5

```
2218               /* The following is a manual expansion of argmatch_valid,
2219                  but with the added "+ ..." description and the [posix-]
2220                  prefixes prepended.  Note that this simplification works
2221                  only because all four existing time_style_types values
2222                  are distinct.  */
2223               fputs (_("Valid arguments are:\n"), stderr);
2224               char const *const *p = time_style_args;
2225               while (*p)
2226                 fprintf (stderr, "  - [posix-]%s\n", *p++);
2227               fputs (_("  - +FORMAT (e.g., +%H:%M) for a 'date'-style"
2228                        " format\n"), stderr);
2229               usage (LS_FAILURE);
```

Triggered when using invalid time format name:

```
$ LANG=C ls -l --time-style=whatever 
ls: invalid argument 'whatever' for 'time style'
Valid arguments are:
  - [posix-]full-iso
  - [posix-]long-iso
  - [posix-]iso
  - [posix-]locale
  - +FORMAT (e.g., +%H:%M) for a 'date'-style format
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

$ echo $?
2
```

## Case 6

```
2669 static void
2670 set_exit_status (bool serious)
2671 {
2672   if (serious)
2673     exit_status = LS_FAILURE;
2674   else if (exit_status == EXIT_SUCCESS)
2675     exit_status = LS_MINOR_PROBLEM;
2676 }
```

This (serious = true) can happen in multiple cases, for example if there is a loop somewhere:

```
2747       /* If we've already visited this dev/inode pair, warn that
2748          we've found a loop, and do not process this directory.  */
2749       if (visit_dir (dir_stat.st_dev, dir_stat.st_ino))
2750         {
2751           error (0, 0, _("%s: not listing already-listed directory"),
2752                  quotef (name));
2753           closedir (dirp);
2754           set_exit_status (true);
2755           return;
2756         }
```

It can also happen for many other cases, based on arguments.
`file_failure` first argument is the boolean passed to `set_exit_status`

### Subcase A

```
2710 /* Read directory NAME, and list the files in it.
2711    If REALNAME is nonzero, print its name instead of NAME;
2712    this is used for symbolic links to directories.
2713    COMMAND_LINE_ARG means this directory was mentioned on the command line.  */

...

2725   if (!dirp)
2726     {
2727       file_failure (command_line_arg, _("cannot open directory %s"), name);
2728       return;
2729     }
```

So for example:

```
$ ls /thatDOESnotEXIST >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
2
```

### Subcase B

```
2736       /* If dirfd failed, endure the overhead of using stat.  */
2737       if ((0 <= fd
2738            ? fstat (fd, &dir_stat)
2739            : stat (name, &dir_stat)) < 0)
2740         {
2741           file_failure (command_line_arg,
2742                         _("cannot determine device and inode of %s"), name);
```

That is some kind of directory not available to access (like a remote one).

### Subcase C

```
2771       if (print_hyperlink)
2772         {
2773           absolute_name = canonicalize_filename_mode (name, CAN_MISSING);
2774           if (! absolute_name)
2775             file_failure (command_line_arg,
2776                           _("error canonicalizing %s"), name);
```

or

```
3189       if (print_hyperlink)
3190         {
3191           f->absolute_name = canonicalize_filename_mode (full_name,
3192                                                          CAN_MISSING);
3193           if (! f->absolute_name)
3194             file_failure (command_line_arg,
3195                           _("error canonicalizing %s"), full_name);
```

or

```
3450 static void
3451 get_link_name (char const *filename, struct fileinfo *f, bool command_line_arg)
3452 {
3453   f->linkname = areadlink_with_size (filename, f->stat.st_size);
3454   if (f->linkname == NULL)
3455     file_failure (command_line_arg, _("cannot read symbolic link %s"),
3456                   filename);
3457 }
```

These are some kind of broken hard/soft links.

### Subcase D

```
2836       else if (errno != 0)
2837         {
2838           file_failure (command_line_arg, _("reading directory %s"), name);
```

or

```
2851   if (closedir (dirp) != 0)
2852     {
2853       file_failure (command_line_arg, _("closing directory %s"), name);
```

Another case when it is not possible to read directory content (if provided on command line)

### Subcase E

```
3235       if (err != 0)
3236         {
3237           /* Failure to stat a command line argument leads to
3238              an exit status of 2.  For other files, stat failure
3239              provokes an exit status of 1.  */
3240           file_failure (command_line_arg,
3241                         _("cannot access %s"), full_name);
```

That happens when trying to match files, such as:

```
$ ls '*DOESnotEXIST*' >& /dev/null
$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: Your answer is about `gls`, not `ls`... the standard says exit > 0 in case of errors, not more.

Comment: @schily the question is not about the standard but about what the OP sees in his `ls` manual which clearly shows exit codes `1`  and `2`.

Comment: But since he did not mention which `ls` implementation he is referring to, you should not make assumptions based on `gls`.

Comment: @schily look at the man output from the question. Also the command is still called `ls` even if coming from GNU.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `man ls` (for GNU ls) contains:

> 2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).

Probably, the word `access` should be read as `stat`. An argument (file) that could not be stat (`stat filename`) because it doesn't exists, would generate an error code of `2`.

In short, for GNU `ls`: A command like:

```
ls   NONE_existent_file    # will result in exit 2
```

Try:

```
ls nofile
ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory
echo $?
2
```

Or try:

```
$ ls $(date); echo "exit status: $?"
ls: cannot access 'Wed': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Oct': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '24': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '02:42:02': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'UTC': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '2018': No such file or directory
exit status: 2
```